# Nodes from Figma REST API don't have visible property

Tags: figma-api

I don't know if this the right place to ask this.

Why the nodes I get from REST API didnt have `visible` property? The example from documentation show otherwise.

I retrieved the nodes using axios from `/v1/files/key` endpoint with read-only file content scope access token.

I have changed my access token scope to add dev resources read scope. But the `visible` property still didn't appear in the nodes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.